# catch mouseMoveEvent on Qt5's QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I'm following the reply of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30142751/detect-when-mouse-cursor-is-over-an-irregular-shape-picture-in-qt5-and-qml). But I got stuck U_U.

I'm developing a Qt5 application where I want to catch mouseMoveEvent event when the mouse hovers a QQuickItem item. But I don't know how to make it work.

I have isolated the problematic code (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608535/qquickview-handling-mouse-events-in-c#answer-29610499) code):

**main.cpp**:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQuick>

class MyItem : public QQuickItem
{
public:
    MyItem()
    {
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
        setFlag(ItemAcceptsInputMethod, true);
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        QQuickItem::mousePressEvent(event);
        qDebug() << event->pos();
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        QQuickItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
        qDebug() << event->pos();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView* view = new QQuickView;
    qmlRegisterType<MyItem>("Test", 1, 0, "MyItem");
    view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

import Test 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    MyItem {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Button {
        x: 100
        y: 100
        text: "Button"
    }
}
```

In this example code mousePressEvent is catched, but mouseMoveEvent isn't, Why? I think the solution must be trivial but I cannot see my mistake.

Comment: Maybe you are wanting to override hoverEnterEvent() and/or hoverMoveEvent() and/or hoverLeaveEvent() instead?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. Tomorrow will be a very productive day. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy Friesner's comment I get the working code:

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQuick>

class MyItem : public QQuickItem
{
public:
    MyItem()
    {
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
        setFlag(ItemAcceptsInputMethod, true);
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
    {
        QQuickItem::mousePressEvent(event);
        qDebug() << event->pos();
    }

    //This is function to override:
    void hoverMoveEvent(QHoverEvent* event) {
        QQuickItem::hoverMoveEvent(event);
        qDebug() << event->pos();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView* view = new QQuickView;
    qmlRegisterType<MyItem>("Test", 1, 0, "MyItem");
    view->setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

import Test 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    MyItem {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    Button {
        x: 100
        y: 100
        text: "Button"
    }
}
```